# Unable to resolve artifacts defined in dependencyManagement from Jenkins on CentOS7

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have Jenkins running on a CentOS7 box behind a firewall.
I am using a Jenkins installed version of Maven.
I have configured a mirror in a global settings.xml file in Jenkins to point to our internal Artifactory server.

Dependencies defined in my *dependencies* section get pulled down fine.  However dependencies in my *dependencyManagement* section fail with an error of **ReasonPhrase:Forbidden**

The odd thing is, if I run the build from the command line in the workspace on the Jenkins box, everything runs fine.

Error output:

```
Parsing POMs
    using global settings config with name GlobalMavenSettings
    Replacing all maven server entries not found in credentials list is true
    Failed to transfer Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-heroku-        connector:pom:1.2.2.RELEASE from/to artifactory 
    (http://artifactory.cos.dev:8081/artifactory/repo): Access denied to: http://artifactory.cos.dev:8081/artifactory/repo/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-heroku-connector/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-heroku-connector-1.2.2.RELEASE.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
    ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
    org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were 
    encountered while processing the POMs:
    [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact 
    org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-heroku-connector:pom:1.2.2.RELEASE 
    from/to artifactory (http://artifactory.cos.dev:8081/artifactory/repo): Access denied to: http://artifactory.cos.dev:8081/artifactory/repo/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-heroku-connector/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-heroku-connector-1.2.2.RELEASE.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. @ line 39, column 16

at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:361)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:331)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1326)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1123)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:690)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:542)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
   Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.me.example</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>           
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-heroku-connector</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>               
       </dependencies>         
    </dependencyManagement>     
</project>
```

If I move a dependency from *dependencyManagement* to *dependencies* it will resolve correctly.

Under Jenkins->Managed Files, my global config file has the following mirror.

```
<mirror>
    <id>artifactory</id>
    <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
    <name>My Artifactory</name>
    <url>http://artifactory.cos.dev:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
</mirror>
```

Comment: It looks like the credentials for the server are not correct or neither defined at all.. `Access denied to: http://artifac...`

Comment: khmarbaise, there are no credentials required for resolving dependencies from Artifactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that dependencies defined in *dependencyManagement* use the proxy defined in Jenkins, whereas dependencies defined in *dependencies* use the proxy defined in your settings.xml.

Therefore adding a -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts= to my /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file fixed things.